# preview the data from a exported .mysql file without loading into MySQL

Tags: server, mysql

What I want to do is preview an exported SQL file without having to load it into the MySQL server. Many of my exported or backup files have the same names, but different dates and locations. In simple terms I want to validate that the example.sql or example.sql.gz has the correct data.

Most of these are very large from a Magento database for a on-line store. I grow tired creating and destroying databases in PhpMyAdmin or MYSQL workbench. Also some are corrupting the Magento Application or producing errors so they can't be run in Magento Webpage Browser. Running Magento Webpage Browser would be the final step to discover if this would be the correct database.

Currently they load in Gedit but due to their size it eats my resources and takes forever to load! on suggestion was to use vim, but I was hopping for something with a Gui or more user friendly?
[Ubuntu 14.04.5-LTS] [Gnome Desktop] [8 core. 32 Gig AMD]

Thanks for you time,
 James

Comment: Have you tried a simple pager (such as `less`)?

Comment: I did try "Gvim" from the Ubuntu Software Center and I at least have a nice text search and scrollbars, plus the screen definition makes it easier to use then just vim. Perhaps if I could have more then one MySQL server so the second could be used for testing? Maybe a KVM server as my HP x9400 workstation has great resources [8 cores and 32 gig of RAM, with six HDD's] with Dual I/O ports